# Resume parser in Ruby/(Rails Plugin/Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any ruby gem/ rails plugin available for parsing the resume and importing that information into an object/form ?

Comment: What do you mean with Resume? Are you talking about Curriculum Vitae?

Comment: @weppos - yes resume/CV. If I allow the user to upload their CV (in word document), I need to deduce the information and store it in the database. Information like name, address, email, phone, summary, skills, jobs, education, ...

Comment: @Dharam  I know I am writing very late, but now after 4 yrs of your hunt, you will find lot of companies working in this domain. And they do integrate with ROR  see  [Rchilli Resume parser](http://www.rchilli.com) ,  Hireability (http://hireabiliti.com) ,  Daxtra (http://www.daxtraa.com).  Try any of these I am sure you can integrate with ROR in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you'll find anything *completely* automated to do this, because a résumé (or CV) can be structured in so many different ways and can contain very different types of data. Any completely automated solution is likely to have accuracy problems, since it is technically a difficult problem to solve.

You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451943/best-3rd-party-resume-parser-tool/529291#529291) useful.

Here are some other suggestions that might help :-

- Require a user to enter their details into a form on your website instead of uploading a Word document. You'll then be able to explicitly ask for the data you want and you'll be able to store the data in a structure that suits you. However, this may be too much of a barrier to entry for your users.
- Allow a user to submit the URL of their résumé published using the [hResume microformat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HResume). Sites like [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/) already publish résumés in this format. There is a Ruby gem [mofo](http://mofo.rubyforge.org/) which can parse microformats including hResumes. However, not all users will have an on-line résumé like this.

Comment: @floehopper - thanks for the feedback. Good to know about hResume microformat and mofo. I will try mofo.